# jQuery смена background по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть у меня целый список элементов-ссылок. Каждому присвоен класс .clm и различные id. И есть классы в CSS с такими точно именами как и id, но по умолчанию они выключены. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку имя id каким-то образом вытягивалось в переменную и для .back-image (класс, где меняется фон) добавлялся класс дополнительный из тех скрытых {addClass(this.id) } То есть имя id должно включать класс с таким же именем.
Немного кода.
CSS:

```
//по умолчанию они нигде не присвоены, назовем их "скрытые".
    .arts{
        background: url("../images/arts.svg") no-repeat center center;
    }
    .video{
        background: url("../images/video.svg") no-repeat center center;
    }
```

(x)HTML:

```
<a xlink:href="#" id="arts" class="clm">Arts</a>
<a xlink:href="#" id="video" class="clm">Video</a>

<div class="back_img"></div> //там меняется фон, который добавляется из какого-либо скрытого класса
```

Мой калечный JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clm').клик(получить его id)
});
   $('.clm').click(function()){
    $('.back_img').addClass(класс с именем как и у id)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то так.

```
$('.clm').click(function(){

   var id = $(this).prop('id'); // можно ещё так this.id

   $('.back_img').addClass(id);

});
```

Comment: Да, почти) Только первый раз я могу включить. Но следующие кнопки уже не работают. Я после addClass (и перед пробовал) добавил такую $('.back_img').removeClass(id);, но не работает

Comment: @ArtyomOleynichenko - так объясните, когда должен вызываться `removeClass`  - в вопросе об этом ничего нет.

Comment: Нет, все заработало. Я зря удалил первую $(document).ready(function() - без неё не работало. Спасибо )

Comment: Только если часто будешь кликать, то может сразу два класса добавиться. Можно добавить логики с `.hasClass()` или `.toggleClass()` или хардкорно в начале клика делать `$('.back_img').removeClass('arts').removeClass('video')`